# windows defender is calling my script a trojan horse

Tags: windows

I have made a very simple script in python.
I have converted it to an .exe file and tried to run it to test it out, but windows defender is blocking and deleting it by calling it a trojan horse once i download it to my pc.

Do anyone know what i can do in this situation?

On beforehand thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Well if it's your code and you're sure it's not a malware, if you want to test it, before running add exclusion in your windows defender.